# For Loop Count Single Word String Not Work?

Tags: python, string, count

I'm a scrub, but why doesn't this work.

```
def length(x):
    b = 0
    for i in x:
        b += 1
        return b
        print b
```

Gives no output, doesn't print even 0.  Confused.

Trying to count amount of letters in single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one at a time. Put the print or return statement outside the forloop.

```
def length(x):
    b = 0
    for i in x:
        b += 1
    print b
length('foo')
```

Output:

```
3
```

If you want to use return inside the function then call the function within the print statement.

```
def length(x):
    b = 0
    for i in x:
        b += 1
    return b
print length('foo')
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Omg, thank you.  Stupid formatting gets me everytime.